# QT/QML : It is possible to reload model in Listview but not delegate item?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have a Listview which use a model from a XmlListModel. All works fine, but when I reload the model with a Timer, the Delegate item is reload too. 
To be clear, I would reload data in Delegate item, but not the item himself.

Is there an easy to provide this result ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve? Can you show us your code? I think it's wise to heed the advice "State should never be stored in a delegate." - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop

Comment: My code is so ugly, that I can't show here =)  
It's just an Listview popupale by a XMLListModel. In delegate, I've made some Rectangle and some label.  Label values are filled with XmlListmodel Roles. And when I click on an rectangle, color change.  I've a Timer which reload XmlModel every minutes. I would keep color of my Rectangle when XmlModel is reload but I want also to update data in Label.  It seems clearer to you? May be ListView isn't good component to use, may be I should use Repeater. What do you think ?  Thanks.